# 301 redirecting urls with special characters using web.config

Tags: redirects, 301-redirect, windows

I am trying to redirect some old urls containing some special characters. When I place the url on the web.config automatically it gives me a 500 internal server error.

So, how do I translate the special character "&" to get it working.

Comment: Can you mark the question as answered?

Answer (score 2):

The HTTP status code 500 "internal server error" is shown because the URL's you used are not properly escaped.

A quote from [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22181429/how-do-i-use-web-config-to-redirect-to-a-query-string-on-windows-server-2008-r2):

> When adding a query string in the action of a rewrite rule, you've got to escape all the "?" and "&" characters in the URL.

```
? = &#63;
& = &amp;
```

For example the following **won't** work:

```
<action type="Redirect" url="/long_url.aspx?key1=value1&key2=value2" />
```

For example the following **will** work:

```
<action type="Redirect" url="/long_url.aspx&#63;key1=value1&amp;key2=value2" />
```

Comment: @Jose Pena does this answer your question?